# Row number and partition by in MS excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in excel such as:

```
ID        | Fee
123456789 | 100
987654321 | 100
987654321 | 100
987654321 | 50
```

What I do not know how to do is use a similar row_number() over(partition by) in excel that I would normally do in SQL

Partition by (ID and Fee)

Desired output would be

```
ID        | Fee   | rn
123456789 | 100   | 1
987654321 | 100   | 1
987654321 | 100   | 2
987654321 | 50    | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ID` is column `A` and `fee` is column `B` then use the following formula in `C2`:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A2&$B$2:$B2=A2&B2))`

This also works if the data is not in order.

Answer (score 1):

In `C1` you could use:

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),C1+1,1)
```